# How do i check if an Array is filled with a certain value?

Tags: ios, swift

I have array, lets say

```
arr = [1,0,3,5,1,0]
```

How do i check if the entire array contains only 0 values ? I know could use for-loop and check each index repeatedly until i reach the end of an array. 
Like

```
var onlyZeros = false
if arr.count > 0
{
  for i in(0..<arr.count)
  { 
   if arr[i] == 0
    {
      onlyZeros = true
     }
      else
    {
      onlyZeros = false
     }

   }
}
// do something with status of onlyZeros variable.
```

But i want to know if there are any faster / easier ways? Since the array sometimes will be very large. And i want this to happen every time a new value is added to the array.**Nothing should happen if the array is filled with any other numbers (1s 2s or any other number)**.

**Clarification** The function or code should return false if the array is filled with any other number , mixed or repeated.

Eg : [0,0,0,0...] should return TRUE

but [1,1,1,1...] or [2,2,2,2...] or anything else should return FALSE

and [1,2,3,0,0,0...] or anything else should also return FALSE

I searched and found out that

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {
    func allEqual() -> Bool {
        if let firstElem = first {
            return !dropFirst().contains { $0 != firstElem }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

could return true or false if the entire array is filled with same value.

Edit : **I am looking for the fastest method. Thanks.**

Comment: `let arrayContainZeros = arr.filter { (number) -> Bool in
                return  number == 0
            }`

Comment: does this make sense for you?

Comment: @jagdeepsingh Lemme try it.

Comment: *“I am looking for the fastest method”* – any method must traverse through the array until a non-zero element is found, or the end of the array is reached. There is no magic how you can make this faster for large arrays.

Comment: @MartinR True. There could be several different ways to check for this, and i suppose one of them is faster than the other?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon You should undelete your answer since it is the correct one and was incorrectly downvoted, it should even be the accepted answer.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think i didnt see his answer. Trigger happy people.... :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way to check that all elements in your array are all zero is to use the [`Sequence.allSatisfy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2996794-allsatisfy) method and check that each element is equal to zero:

```
let onlyZeros = arr.allSatisfy { $0 == 0 }
```

Comment: This seems to do the job. Thanks , much better than my for-loops !

Comment: No prob! Yeah and as for how fast it is - since it's built into the Swift standard library, I imagine it's been optimized like crazy, so I don't think you're going to get much faster than this.

Answer (score 1):

To check if `array` contains all same values , you can create a **`Set`** from the `array` and check if the `Set` contains a single element.

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func allEqual(to value: Element) -> Bool {
        let set = Set(self)
        return (set.count == 1 && set.first == value)
    }
}
```

In the above code, I've created a *computed property* `allEqual` in `extension  Array`.

**Example:**

```
let arr1 = [1,0,3,5,1,0]
arr1.allEqual(to: 0) //false

let arr2 = [0, 0, 0, 0]
arr2.allEqual(to: 0) //true
```

Comment: you both are correct .. different approach ... so dont worry guys

Comment: @PGDev Wouldn't this return true even arr2 is filled with [1,1,1,1]?

Comment: @Zyfe3r You said you want to only check if all are same or not right?

Comment: @PGDev No sir. That extension on my question can find out if the array if filled with same number or not. What i want to do is, check if my array is filled with [0,0,0,0..], i dont want anything to happen if its [1,1,1,] or [2,2,2,2] or [3,3,3...... I edited the question and made it much more clear.

Comment: @Zyfe3r Updated the answer as per your requirement.

Answer (score -4):

Do you mean its an empty array without a value?

if its that the case, you can use other pre-defined functions like empty(), isset() to check the array by using if/else statement.

Comment: `isEmpty` won't work as it contains value count not the actual values

Comment: What programming language you use for this?

Comment: `Swift`, I think question is for `iOS`.

Comment: No. Its not an empty array. It would be an array with [0,0,0,0.....] values. Every index having an int value of 0